# Consul UI and service-discovery doesn't update services

Tags: mesos, marathon, service-discovery, consul, dnsmasq

Consul user interface doesn't update the services when they change. The problem is that I launch a example.json to marathon and it appear as a service in consul user interface but when I delete that app from marathon, it doesn't delete from the consul UI it is there.
What could it be?

Comment: How do you register service in Consul? Be design consul doesn't remove unhealthy services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ciscocloud/mesos-consul  to register mesos apps with consul,  works great

```
 {
  "id": "/mesos-consul",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 0.33,
  "mem": 128,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [],
    "docker": {
      "image": "ciscocloud/mesos-consul",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 0,
          "hostPort": 0,
          "servicePort": 10004,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "labels": {}
        }
      ],
      "privileged": false,
      "parameters": [],
      "forcePullImage": false
    }
  },
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 10004,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ],
  "args": [
    "--zk=zk://zookeeper-hostname:2181/mesos",
    "--mesos-ip-order=mesos",
    "--log-level=err",
    "--refresh=1s"
  ]
}
```

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/CiscoCloud/marathon-consul/issues/17#issuecomment-161678453) CiscoCloud team moved from Consul to Traefik so maybe you could be interested to move to [allegro/marathon-consul](https://github.com/allegro/marathon-consul). If you need to support only Marathon services it probably will works better since its using Marathon events instead and provides more configuration options + health checking.